# Any wireless chipsets with open specifications?

Tags: hardware, wireless, specifications

I'm wondering if there's any "mainstream" wireless chipsets/adapters for PC's that have open specifications, to a level that would permit one to implement a custom driver (i.e. specifications of registers, mode of operation etc.)? It's OK if the chipset requires the upload of binary blobs (for which the source isn't available) to the chip/card itself etc. as long as the host <-> adapter interface is public. I'm looking for it mainly out of interest to see what this interface looks like, but I might also be interested in doing some coding myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have OpenWRT which is a fully capable open source router operation system, TP-LINK products are based on OpenWRT.

You may be also interested in https://www.zigbee.org/ more oriented to the Internet of Things and M2M wireless sensor networks.

Comment: Thanks but what I'm really interested in is the interface between operating system and the wireless chip. I.e. what it looks like at the "register level", how much of the 'discovery' phase that is polling vs pushing etc. OpenWRT probably has code in it that participates in this, but I'm really looking for the specifications.

Comment: Well, in this case it depends on the chip you want to use, there are many on the market and all of them have open specifications, for example the AR9331 http://www.openhacks.com/uploadsproductos/ar9331_datasheet.pdf

Comment: OK - I've been looking at some mainstream products and I can't find datasheets for those. Such as Intel Wireless PRO or Ralink RT2860 which are very commonly used. I've only been able to find very superficial information like the performance etc. of the device. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check the Atheros WiFi chipset and its open source drivers, for examples ath5k and ath9k. These drivers are preinstalled in Linux kernel. It's widely used in academy, at least, and adopted by many off-the-shelf NIC.